# Change orientation without rotating device

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, orientation

I have app that's mainly in Landscape orientation ... and I have 2 views that are in portrait and they appear when it's changing it's orientation. So far so good.

But on one of those views I have a button that has to push a view in Landscape orientation without rotating the ipad.

How can I achiev this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the button action event, try: viewWantedChange.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to implement a user interface experience fail to me. Present it in portrait (current user' device orientation) and allow the user to rotate to landscape if they want to. I think forcing the user to continually rotate the device provides a very bad experience for them.

Comment: it's not my decision ... I have to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Set the view you want in landscape orientation to Landscape orientation in the interface builder (it probably is in inherited), and set the should auto rotate method to return only true to landscape.

Comment: did that ... and it's in landscape ... kinda. but it's cut down and presented in portrait (256 pixels empty underneath and 256 pixels going offscreen)

Comment: because now you have to adjust that view specifically for how you want it to be presented in landscape mode. You probably wanted to apply the apple autorotation method so that everything would be automatically adjusted right?

Comment: readjusting is the best way, since it will be presented always in landscape (like place everything where you want it in the interface builder). the other option is to apply a transform to the view to make everything contained in it rotate but i dont recomend it. additionally i THINK you can call apples rotate method on your view controller but i think thats undocumented api.

Answer (score 0):

you can set device orientation whatever you want by this method at any time.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

this will give you warring that this method is deprecated but it's work fine still iOS 5.1 update so no need to about warning while using this method.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I'm on snow leopard and I cannot build for 5.1